# Best Approach to capture QML component as OpenGLFrameBuffer without display( offline )

Tags: image, qt, qml, framebuffer, qtembedded

I have a requireemnt, to render framebuffer quick as possible so that image updates( time stamp updates on qml ) rendered as imane and send across a network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally I got One approach, which I think best to write QML to FrameBuffer**

Find the sample [here](https://github.com/Ashifta/qmlofflinesceen) using QQuickRenderControl, to write qml component into a framebuffer and save as PNG

Time Elapsed to update QML and Render as QImage(1080X1920): 7ms to 15 ms(Ubuntu OS Lenovo 6th Gen Laptop)